# Переопределение операторов сравнения в swift

Tags: swift, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Доброго времени суток, я хотел бы узнать, как переопределись оператор сравнения в шаблонном классе?

```
 class Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    init(x: Double, y: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    static func < (left: Point, right: Point) -> Bool {
        return (left.x < right.x) && (left.y < right.y)
    }
}
```

В таком случае всё хорошо и работает.
Но почему не работает в таком случае?

```
class ListNode<T> {
    var data: T
    var next: ListNode<T>?
    weak var previus: ListNode<T>?

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }

    static func < (left: ListNode<T>, right: ListNode<T>) -> Bool {
        return (left.data < right.data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает потому что компилятор не знает что Вы будете передавать как T. Чтобы можно было сравнивать, T должен быть сравниваемым:

```
class ListNode<T: Comparable> {
```